# when we are testing the webrtc in the chrome is it uses the native code and jni code that written in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, webrtc, aec, apprtcdemo

I am working on webrtc project in my office.
And i need to test webrtc for to know the flow of the function calls.

i tried testing the webrtc using google apprtc from their website appspot in my android chrome browser and other browsers.

I also used skype, line, and other apps.

But i was unable to see the logs when i used the command "sudo  adb logcat" in my pc.

I was testing in odroidx2 board.

Is it correct way to test the webrtc flow?

Or is there any other way to do that?

I tried this and i didnt find any answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's Web-RTC internals has all the data flow(call initiation, SDP negotiation, ice gathering etc). You can get to it from any version of Chrome by going to chrome://webrtc-internals/

For Android you can debug pages themselves only through[Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging). There you can see where Apprtc makes javascript calls and what JS functions are called when.

Both of those tools should give you plenty of information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to set up remote chrome debugging

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging